# Angular 7 - no headers in response

Tags: angular, http, header, http-headers, angular7

I've got just a weird problem with headers in Angular 7.

I want to execute POST request:

```
this.http.post(this.loginUrl, payload, {observe: 'response'})
    .subscribe((resp: HttpResponse<any>) => 
         console.log(resp.headers.get('Authentication')));
```

In response I don't receive headers without `Content-Type`, and `Pragma`.

**Response from Postman**

[image]

**Response from Google Chrome**

[image]

**Always I got undefined headers list:**

[image]

Anyone could help me? Please so much.

Comment: What is your problem, exactly? You have an `Authorization` header on both images you set here. You want to read it? You cannot do that the way you've shown, that  `response` is just the Http Response body, already parsed from JSON.

Comment: @Zlatko my problem is that I want my Authorization header and I cannot do that. I expect response for example like picture above. I want to fetch my header from response.